# ABI filters of extended Build Variants do not overrides its parents

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, abi, build-variant

In a project i need specific ABI filters per **release** and **debug** and some extneded build variants. It is ok and works fine with **debug** and **release**.

```
 release {
.
.
.
    ndk {
        abiFilters 'armeabi'
        }

}
debug {
.
.
.
    ndk {
        abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi'
        }
}
```

When i extend new buildvariant that init each of these tow variants, abifilters is remained and do not change. For example i have **debug_on_mainserver** that inits **debug**. but i want to add another abiFilter. But it is still use **debug** abiFilters.

```
debug_on_mainserver {
    initWith(buildTypes.debug)
    .
    .
    .
    ndk {
        abiFilters 'armeabi'
        }
}
```

I should say that may i can achive this with Flavor but i use 3 flavor for another reason (store type and handle store config and variables) and i do not want to add another flavor and mulitple my buildVariants variety. Beacuse it is logically should include in **debug_on_mainserver**.
How i can exclude or remove base abiFilters and add new one? Or is it another way to achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by adding `abitFilters.clear()` like so:

```
debug_on_mainserver {
    initWith(buildTypes.debug)
    .
    .
    .
    ndk {
        abiFilters.clear()
        abiFilters 'armeabi'
    }
}
```

The reason this is necessary is because `abiFilters 'string'` is not a setter for `abiFilters`; it adds `'string'` to the existing `MutableSet<String>` of ABI filters, which is inherited from the parent build type.